# why wont this program terminate?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, terminate

I am trying to teach myself python and have no experience write code. For my first attempt I am trying to write a program that applies the snowball principle to debt reduction, but also adds in an extra set amount each payment. I can get the first debt to clear(it goes to a negative but it exits the loop). My second step wont exit the loop and I have looked at topics that dealt with nested loops but they did not help. Could someone please show me where I went wrong?

```
#Temp fixed number for testing use rawinput for actual program.

#name the debt
debt1 = "CC A"
#currnet balnace
balance1 = float(5000)
#APR
annualInterestRate1 = float(.1499)
#Currnet Monthly Payment
minMonthlyPayment1 = float(200)
# Exta Payment
boosterPayment = float(337)

print "The balance on ",debt1," is ",balance1

debt2 = "CC B"
balance2 = float(1000)
annualInterestRate2 = float(.1499)
minMonthlyPayment2 = float(200)

print "The balance on ",debt2," is ",balance2

debt3 = "ICCU"
balance3 = float(6000)
annualInterestRate3 = float(.0879)
minMonthlyPayment3 = float(130)

print "The balance on ",debt3," is ",balance3

debt4 = "Car"
balance4 = float(8000)
annualInterestRate4 = float(.0699)
minMonthlyPayment4 = float(200)

print "The balance on ",debt4," is ",balance4

debt5 = "Truck"
balance5 = float(15000)
annualInterestRate5 = float(.0439)
minMonthlyPayment5 = float(333)

#nubmer of payments made durning the debt reduction. Used as the index.
numPay = 0
save = 0

#For Debt1 with an APR greater then 0
intPayment1 = round(balance1*(annualInterestRate1/12),2)

while balance1 >= 0:
    #payment with intrest
    payment1 = minMonthlyPayment1 - intPayment1 + boosterPayment
    #subtact payment from balance
    balance1 -= payment1
    #count Number of payments
    numPay += 1
print numPay
print balance1

#For Debt2 with an APR greater then 0

#Figures monthly charge based on given APR
intPayment2 = round(balance2*(annualInterestRate2/12),2)
#Monthly payment minus intrest
standPay2 = minMonthlyPayment2 - intPayment2

while balance2 >= 0:
    #payment while debt1 is being paid

    #need a way to pay the payments while the other debt is being figured
    backPay = numPay
    while backPay >= 0:
        balance2 -= standPay2
        backPay += 1
    #payment with intrest takes 100 away for savings
    payment2 = minMonthlyPayment2 - intPayment2 + (boosterPayment-100)
    #subtact payment from balance
    balance2 -= payment2
    #count Number of payments
    numPay += 1
    #keep track of how much is going to savings
    save += 100
print numPay
print balance1
print save
```

Comment: Is `balance2` ever less than zero?

Comment: while backPay >= 0, backPay += 1

Comment: You will also want to find good ways to debug if you're to start learning code. Try adding print statements at different parts of your code where you think the bug could be. From there check if the expected input is similar to the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this loop:

```
while backPay >= 0:
    balance2 -= standPay2
    backPay += 1
```

Here, `backPay` in increased in each iteration, so the condition `backPay >= 0` will always be true.

Not sure what the code is intended to do, but probably you have to do `backPay -= 1` instead. However, note that since the number of iterations of the loop is known beforehand, and you are just adding a fixed number in each iteration, you could just as well replace the loop with a simple multiplication.

Comment: I had originally went with the multiplication route but realized that I need to adjust for the fact that in `intPayment2 = round(balance2*(annualInterestRate2/12),2)` `intPayment2` will change as `balance2` decreases. `backPay` is my attempt at making a loop that will adjust for the changing value in `balance2`. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @nsidla1327 But neither `intPayment2` nor `standPay2` change _inside of the loop_, so the loop (with `backPay -= 1`) seems to be equivalent to `balance2 -= standPay * (backPay + 1)`. Anyway, glad I could help.